# Ubuntu 18.04 switch back to synaptics as input driver

Tags: synaptics, libinput

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on different thinkpads and the trackpoint is very jumpy and inprecise to use.

I installed the newest Libinput packages: libinput10_1.12.1-1, libinput-bin_1.12.1-1 and xserver-xorg-input-libinput_0.28.0-1 but that didn't change much.

So my question: Is it possible to switch back to the old synaptics driver that worked well for me under Ubuntu 16.04.

I tried with intalling xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and removing xserver-xorg-input-libinput but then neither the keyboard nor the mouse/trackpoint worked. If I don't remove ...libinput nothing changes.

Answer (score 4):

If someone else is interessted in solving this questions:

install: xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and xserver-xorg-input-evdev

remove: xserver-xorg-input-libinput

and as far as I just figured out it works.

Comment: after removing xserver-xorg-input-libinput keyboard stopped working (Ubuntu 22.04)